# what is the meaning of 'landing pattern' in designing IC footprint?

Tags: integrated-circuit, eaglecad, footprint

I am designing the footprint of an IC using this tutorial http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Cadsoft_Eagle_how_to_make_parts_tutorial
In that they have mentiond: "Important: It's very important to have the landing pattern and not just the pin dimensions. Some datasheets will only give the pin size, the landing pattern is larger and optimized to help the chip solder easily. "
My question is: I have these specifications:

[image]
The distance in the top left image is the size of the landing pattern right?

Comment: You expect hundreds of people to read your question but yet you can't bother to rotate the image?

Comment: The usual term is "land pattern" not "landing...". Think about an aerial photo or Google Earth image showing the arrangement of fields and roads, only smaller...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a typical SMD package, in this case for an SSOP part with a central thermal pad.

[image]

If we look up close at one of the pins, it looks like this:

[image]

The pin is the white rectangle.  This is actually unimportant to the PCB fabrication process, and is often left off of the drawing.  In any case, if it exists it is put in the tDocu (documentation) layer 51 in Eagle, and is just for reference.

The cross-hatched pinkish-red pattern is the important part.  It is the dimension of the pad, where the solder will be, and is what the pin is soldered to.  It is created using the SMD tool in the Eagle library editor, and is in the component layer, just like a trace on the board (Top, layer 1).  It is actually red; there are two other layers on top creating the cross-hatching and making it look pinkish as explained below.

[image]

As your document pointed out, the pad needs to be larger than the actual pin for the part to locate itself properly. In addition to your pin dimensions, your documentation should also give suggested dimensions for the pads (Recommended Pad Layout or something similar).

If for whatever reason the document does not provide this information, you can draw the pads somewhat larger than the pins, as shown on the example here.

The outside white cross-hatched pattern is the solder mask.  It is created automatically when you create the pad.  It keeps solder from bridging from one pin to the next, and is in the tStop layer 29.

Finally there is the "cream" layer, which is used for generating a stencil to apply solder paste to the pad.  It is also automatically generated when you create the pad and is the same size as the pad.  It is drawn with a wider white cross-hatched pattern and is in the tCream layer 31.

The combination of the white solder-mask and cream cross-hatching make the pad look pinkish; if you disable both layers 29 and 31 the pad by itself is a dark red.

Creating your own packages is one of the more daunting tasks undertaken by a new Eagle user, but after you've done a dozen or so it becomes second nature.

Comment: Good explanation, but you didn't actually answer his question. Land pattern is an unambiguous name for the pcb footprint. It is distinguished from footprint because this can also refer to the physical dimensions of the device. The image posted appears to show the device dimensions, not the land pattern. So no, the dimension in the top left is probably not the land pattern size.

Comment: @loganf yes, I agree that the page of the document he has in his post has nothing to do with the PCB footprint. That's why I mentioned his document should have a section titled recommended solder pad layout.  Often it is on a separate page from the one with the overall dimensions of the part.